# How do you set margins for the various browsers in CSS

Tags: css, margins

I often look at code and see stuff like "-moz such and such CSS rules, -webkit such and such CSS rules" and think I need to do something like that in my case.

My page http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/ needs to appear as it does in firefox, but when I look at it in Chrome and Safari, it's completely backwards. In Firefox I could not get the margins how I wanted them to be with regular margins, that is - I had to use negative integers for the margins. What can I do to have the margins be the same in all browsers?

Here's my CSS on just one of the divs (I think I can apply any answer to the rest)

```
     .colorScheme {background-color:#B9E9DA; width:500px; height: 340px; margin-top:-45px; padding:0;}
```

but you will clearly see the brokenness of it when you look at it in any browser other than FF.

Thanks for looking and helping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this you will have to test but I believe you can solve your problem as follows.

```
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.colorScheme {
background-color:#B9E9DA; 
width:500px; 
height: 340px; 
margin-top:-45px; 
padding:0;
}
```

This will set all elements to have no padding or margin. Giving you control using CSS for all paddings and margins.

Alternatively you can just assign hardcoded to the single class but you will need to assign a value to EACH margin/Padding as follows

```
.colorScheme {
background-color:#B9E9DA; 
width:500px; 
height: 340px; 
margin:-45px 0 0 0; 
padding:0;
}
```

Try those and see if they work out for you.

Comment: I can't do any resets to the global style sheet, but I'll try setting each margin. perhaps that will work. Let's see, said the blind.

Comment: no that doesn't do it. The problem is, I think, that the parts below the nav, that begins with "A Note From Kristen", and past issues is broken into two different parts. They are in divs (the latter floats right) and they are two widgets it seems inside of the CMS (eZPublisher) and there is no container of those two divs where I can simply pull the top up, effecting them both simultaneously. However, the Chrome and Safari renditions of them are fine, but with Mozilla and IE, there is the white vertical space between the nav and the following sections.

Comment: I think that if I simply set a browser-specific selector onto the rule like I see so much (like so: -moz, -ie, etc) it will do the trick for me. But can you do that to inline styles?